# Xamarin - ‘Android.Content.IntentFilter' is not an attribute class

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

I’ve created an Android class library that includes an implementation of a broadcast receiver:

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY" }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@"})]
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public GcmBroadcastReceiver ()
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to build I’m getting the message “‘Android.Content.IntentFilter' is not an attribute class”

What do I need to do to make this build?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add using statements for both Android.Content and Android.App